# githubのブラウザ上でgitignoreが作成できない

Tags: github

GitHubを使っているのですが、.gitignoreを作成したいと思ってcreate new fileで.gitignoreの内容を書いてcommit new fileしようと思ったのですが、commit new fileのボタンが押せません。なぜかわかりますか？
[image: ボタンの状態]
後、そもそもローカルで書いてpushしろよと思うかもしれませんが、macで.gitignoreをテキストエディットで作成すると、なぜか.gitignore.txtになってしまって使えません。
これもなぜだかわかる方いますか？

Comment: > `macで.gitignoreをテキストエディットで作成すると、なぜか.gitignore.txtになってしまって使えません。` これは、テキストエディットを利用しているからでは無いでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。touchコマンドで作成したものをテキストエディットで編集したところうまくいきました。どうやらテキストエディットで作成すると、絶対に.txtになるようですね

Answer (score 2):

`touch` コマンドで作成したものをテキストエディットで編集したところうまくいきました。
どうやら mac のテキストエディットで新規作成すると、絶対に `.txt` になるようですね。

---

*この投稿は [@はじめてgitマン さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/52166/github%e3%81%ae%e3%83%96%e3%83%a9%e3%82%a6%e3%82%b6%e4%b8%8a%e3%81%a7gitignore%e3%81%8c%e4%bd%9c%e6%88%90%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84#comment54479_52166) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*